# Serial Port not receiving any data

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino

I'm trying to write a simple c# console application to read/write from a serial port that communicates to an Arduino that I have hooked up. The problem that I'm running into is that I can write to the Arduino no problem, but I am unable to receive any data back. My serial port's `SerialDataReceivedEventHandler` isn't ever being fired either, but I'm guessing those two issues are related.

I know it isn't my Arduino that is causing the problem because when using the Arduino IDE I am able to receive data without any problems. Here is what I've got code wise for now:

```
SerialPort sPort = new SerialPort();
sPort.PortName = SerialPort.GetPortNames()[0];
sPort.BaudRate = 9600;
sPort.Parity = Parity.None;
sPort.DataBits = 8;
sPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
sPort.RtsEnable = false;
sPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

sPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sPort_dataReceived);
sPort.ErrorReceived += new SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler(sPort_ErrorReceived);

sPort.Open();

Console.Read();
sPort.Write("tt_calib");

while (true)
{
    if (sPort.ReadExisting() != string.Empty)
        Console.WriteLine(sPort.ReadExisting());
}
```

I am aware that I don't close the port in this code, that is not the issue as I am able to rerun and open it every time. This code is also not in its final form, I'm attempting to get the read event working so that I can react to various messages differently. I've read what seems like every question but no solution I've found seems to do the trick.

This is a C# .NET 4.5 console application running on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It ended up being a stupid simple issue. Instead of `sPort.RtsEnable = false;` it should be `true`. All events now trigger and I am able to read.

Answer (score 5):

With C# in VS2019 available cross-platform, I ran into the same issue on my VM (Parallels+Windows10) and my host machine (MacOS).
Setting DTR to true did the trick

Comment: Using .NET 6, Windows 10, setting DtrEnable = true and RtsEnable = true did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

```
mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                    object sender,
                    SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
    Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
    Console.Write(indata);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Tsukasa! I forgot to include this part of my code, but my lack of that function is not the reason the event is not being called. In my code that function was both assigned and defined.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and finally realized that my hardware flow control setting is bios configurable and my setting was **DISABLED**! doh